# Add new column with calculated values

Tags: python, calculated-columns

I want to add a new column called 'NormalizedAnnualCompensation' to my df and populate the column with values from one of three calculations:

1. keep value 2 if value 1 is labeled "Yearly", or
2. multiply it by 12 if labeled "Monthly",
3. or multiply it by 52 if labeled "Weekly."

The two existing columns have dtype INT64. The first called column contains values [Yearly, Monthly, Weekly]; the second called column contains salary totals. I running Python 3 in a Jup Notebook.

- Is the code for each calculation correct?
- How do I trigger the calculations to run through the new column?

I tried writing an if statement and later placed it in a for loop. Neither worked.

```
df.insert(31,['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'],
          
# (also tried:) for x in df['CompFreq']:
    
        if df['CompFreq'] == "Yearly":
            df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal']

        elif df['CompFreq'] == "Monthly":
            df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal']*12

        elif df['CompFreq'] == "Weekly":
            df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal']*52

        else: 
            print(df['CompFreq'].index "not valid")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.DataFrame.replace)to compute the factor for `"CompTotal"`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"CompFreq": "Yearly", "CompTotal": 100}, 
    {"CompFreq": "Monthly", "CompTotal": 10}, 
    {"CompFreq": "Weekly", "CompTotal": 1},
])

factor = df["CompFreq"].replace({"Yearly": 1, "Monthly": 12, "Weekly": 52})
normalized = factor * df["CompTotal"]
df["NormalizedAnnualCompensation"] = normalized
```

If you want something more like `if`, you can use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html?highlight=where#pandas.DataFrame.where):

```py
normalized = df["CompTotal"].where(
    df["CompFreq"] == "Yearly", 
    (12 * df["CompTotal"]).where(
        df["CompFreq"] == "Monthly", 
        52 * df["CompTotal"]
    )
)
```

However, I'd recommend the first option with `replace` for readability.

Comment: Thank you, @cherrywoods! This worked. I was too attached to using the strings instead of transforming them. I really appreciate your time.